# ASP.net: Crystal Reports - Subreport over multiple pages

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, paging, subreport

I have a Crystal Report that has a header and a subreport with the height locked at a exact amount so the subreport will display a maximum of 20 rows on the page.

However, this limitation has restricted the use of the system, and the users now require an unlimited number of rows in the subreport.

I wish to keep the same layout as the report currently is, however the first 20 rows of the subreport will be on Page1, the next 20 rows (21-40) will be on Page 2, and so on.

How would I modify the logic in the Crystal Report to allow this kind of functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Crystal Reports handy, but off the top of my head you can try adding a formula to the subreport's detail New Page After, by doing something like this:

```
RecordNumber Mod 20 = 0
```

For every 20th record, the subreport should page break after the detail.

Comment: It was actually "RecordNumber", and testing directly on the subreport, however, when i reimport the subreport back into my main report, the change isn't replicated.  

I checked the properties of the subreport object, and enabled the "can grow" checkbox.  When the report is rerun, rows 21-40 are at the top of second page, overwriting the header which should be the same as the first page.

Previously, I added a series of blank rows at the end of the subreport's footer to "fill-in" and remaining rows, these are also on the second page.

How do I fix the subreport to stay within its area?

Comment: Two questions -- is your header information in the page header or detail section? and is your subreport in the detail section, or somewhere else?   I tested a report with the header information in Page Header, and the subreport in the details, and it displayed as expected; the subreport stayed at the bottom of the report, and showed 20 records per page.

Comment: Here is the layout of the report:
[Section1 (Report Header)]
[Section2 (Page Header)]
Header - Number - Logo
[GroupHeaderSection1 (Group Header #1 - Invoice.InvoiceID - A)]
*EMPTY*, but same height as Section 2
[DetailSection1 (Details a)]
Customer Details and Address (included as a subreport)
[DetailSection2 (Details b)]
Invoice Line - subreport (first 20 lines visible)
[DetailSection3 (Details c)]
Terms & conditions, our contact details
[GroupHeaderSection1 (Group Header #1 - Invoice.InvoiceID - A)]
*EMPTY*
[Section4 (ReportFooter)]
*EMPTY*
[Section5 (PageFooter)]
*EMPTY*

Comment: Yeah, short of redesigning your report, and not really knowing your data structures, I can't think of any way to have your subreport span multiple pages while still keeping the header and details above and below intact. I'd be happy to put a bounty on this if you want to get more visibility.

Comment: It might be best if I redesign the report. I thought that through the magic wizardry of Crystal Reports there must be some way. Thanks, I'll keep you posted.